# how to make a nested list based on 2 columns?

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame. I wanna make a nested list of a column based another column.

```
col1      col2
As     K
SD     k
JK     K
LO     P
WQ     p
IU     A
```

each element of the nested list is a list of items in `col1` that have the same values in `col2`.

output

```
Nlist= [[As,SD,JK],[LO,WQ],[A]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a combination of `groupby()` and `.tolist()`. However, you would need to first normalize your `col2`:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.lower()
output = df.groupby('col2')['col1'].apply(list).tolist()
```

This outputs:

```
[['IU'], ['As', 'SD', 'JK'], ['LO', 'WQ']]
```

Comment: Can add `sort=False` to get in the same order as OP. `output = df.groupby(df['col2'].str.lower(), sort=False)['col1'].agg(list).tolist()`